# Write numbers and draw rectangles with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I am trying to draw a below given diagram for myself. I have been able to draw the rectangles using `\foreach`  however I am unable to write numbers below the boxes as shown. Could somebody help me in drawing such a diagram.

Here is my code, it is IEEE Tran's code. Also, please see that I have manually added numbers from 1 to n, I want to do it using `\foreach` command. Kindly do not give negative voting because I am beginner with Tikz and this forum.

Please answer one more question- is there a way I can initialize `x` and `y` coordinates as `x = 1` and `y = 1` in the starting of the Tikz figure and then draw all the blocks/rectangles using reference coordinates?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\else
\fi
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,tikz}


\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\maketitle

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
I wish you the best of success.

\begin{tikzpicture}
%Can I give a reference coordinate such as x = 0 and y = 0 and then draw figures
%based on that reference points through out the picture?

\draw [rounded corners](0,0) rectangle +(9,6);

\draw [rounded corners](0.15,0.5) node[above right, font =\small,align=center,text width = 2cm]{YYYY} rectangle +(2.25,5);

\foreach \x in {2.5}
    \foreach \y in {0.5,3,4.5}
    {
    \draw [rounded corners] (\x,\y) rectangle +(6.35,1);

    }

\foreach \x in {2.75,4.25,5.75,7.25}
    \foreach \y in {0.9,3.4,4.9}
    {
    \draw [rounded corners] (\x, \y) node[above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {XXX} rectangle +(1.2,0.5);
    }
\node at (2.75,4.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {1} ;
\node at (2.75,3) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {2} ;
\node at (2.75,0.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {n} ;

\node at (4.25,4.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {n+1} ;
\node at (4.25,3) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {n+2} ;
\node at (4.25,0.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {2n} ;

\node at (5.75,4.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {2n+1} ;
\node at (5.75,3) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {2n+2} ;
\node at (5.75,0.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {3n} ;

\node at (7.25,4.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {3n+1} ;
\node at (7.25,3) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {3n+2} ;
\node at (7.25,0.5) [above right, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.8cm] {4n} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should help us adding the code you have right now (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`). That way you make much more easily our way to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As Manuel says, please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to help when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to illustrate?

Comment: Please remove any code that is not directly related to your question; see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I just did and hopefully it will easy for anyone to answer my questions. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example using two nested `\foreach` loops and `\ifthenelse` from the `ifthen` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    rect/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=green,draw=black,text width=.5cm,text height=.25cm},
    none/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=green!10,draw=gray!20,text width=.5cm,text height=.25cm},
    nmbr/.style={font=\scriptsize,yshift=-.25cm,anchor=north}
]

\newcounter{n}

\foreach \y in {1,...,3} {
  \setcounter{n}{0}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
    \ifthenelse{\y<3}{
      \node[rect] at (\x,-\y) {};
      \node[nmbr] at (\x,-\y) {\ifthenelse{\x=1}{\y} {
        \ifthenelse{\arabic{n}=1}{}{\arabic{n}}n+\y}};
      \stepcounter{n}
    }{
      \stepcounter{n}
      \node[none] at (\x,-\y) {};
      \node[rect] at (\x,-\y-1) {};
      \node[nmbr] at (\x,-\y-1) {\ifthenelse{\x=1}{n}{\arabic{n}n}}; 
    }
  }
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is so cool!!! I am following the Tikz manual, is there any other reference material that I could follow ? How can I learn many other things about \foreach, \ifthenelse ? Please let me know.

Comment: @user56277 You can find a lot of really cool examples at [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).

Comment: I would put all of those in math mode.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 4cm]{geometry} % to avoid `Overfull \hbox' warning
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\vertDistOuter{\fpeval{\distVertOuter+\heightOuter}}
\newcommand*\vertDistOuterTwo[1]{\fpeval{\heightOuter/2+#1*(\heightOuter+\distVertOuter)}}
\newcommand*\horiDistInner{\fpeval{\distHoriInner+\widthInner}}
\newcommand*\horiDistInnerTwo[1]{\fpeval{\distHoriInnerStart+\widthInner/2+#1*(\widthInner+\distHoriInner)}}
\newcommand*\vertDistInner{\fpeval{(\heightOuter-\heightInner)/2}}
\newcommand*\widthTotal{\fpeval{2*\distHoriInnerStart+\boxesInEachRow*\widthInner+(\boxesInEachRow-1)*\distHoriInner} }
\newcommand*\heightTotal{\fpeval{3*\heightOuter+2*\distVertOuter}}

%%% parameters %%%
% spacing
\def\distVertOuter{0.5}
\def\distHoriInnerStart{0.3}
\def\distHoriInner{0.7}
% size of boxes
\def\heightOuter{3}
\def\widthInner{2.5}
\def\heightInner{2}
% number of boxes in each row
\def\boxesInEachRow{4}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\widthTotal,\heightTotal)
  \multido{\r = 0+\vertDistOuter}{3}{%
    \psframe[
      fillstyle = solid,
      fillcolor = blue!60
    ](0,\r)(\widthTotal,\fpeval{\r+\heightOuter})}
  \multido{\rA = \distHoriInnerStart+\horiDistInner}{\boxesInEachRow}{%
    \multido{\rB = \vertDistInner+\vertDistOuter}{3}{%
      \psframe[
        fillstyle = solid,
        fillcolor = green!70!black
      ](\rA,\rB)(\fpeval{\rA+\widthInner},\fpeval{\rB+\heightInner})}}
  \rput(\horiDistInnerTwo{0},\vertDistOuterTwo{2}){$1$}
  \rput(\horiDistInnerTwo{1},\vertDistOuterTwo{2}){$n+1$}
  \multido{\i = 2+1, \r = \horiDistInnerTwo{2}+\horiDistInner}{\fpeval{\boxesInEachRow-2}}{\rput(\r,\vertDistOuterTwo{2}){$\i n+1$}}
  \rput(\horiDistInnerTwo{0},\vertDistOuterTwo{1}){$2$}
  \rput(\horiDistInnerTwo{1},\vertDistOuterTwo{1}){$n+2$}
  \multido{\i = 2+1, \r = \horiDistInnerTwo{2}+\horiDistInner}{\fpeval{\boxesInEachRow-2}}{\rput(\r,\vertDistOuterTwo{1}){$\i n+2$}}
  \rput(\horiDistInnerTwo{0},\vertDistOuterTwo{0}){$n$}
  \multido{\i = 2+1, \r = \horiDistInnerTwo{1}+\horiDistInner}{\fpeval{\boxesInEachRow-1}}{\rput(\r,\vertDistOuterTwo{0}){$\i n$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the values of the parameters and the drawing will automatically adjust.